# How to escape all Special Characters from whole string at one go in Java

Tags: java, lucene

Lucene supports escaping special characters that are part of the query syntax. The current list special characters are

```
+ - && || ! ( ) { } [ ] ^ " ~ * ? : \
```

To escape these character use the \ before the character. For example to search for (1+1):2 use the query:

```
\(1\+1\)\:2
```

**My question is how to escape from whole string at one go?** For example `myStringToEscape = "ABC^ " ~ * ? :DEF";` How to get a **escapedString**.

Answer (score 14):

You can use [`QueryParser.escape`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_6_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/QueryParserBase.html#escape(java.lang.String)), such as:

```
String escapedString = queryParser.escape(searchString);
queryParser.parse("field:" + escapedString);
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are just looking for simple replacement, this will do the trick.

```
String regex = "([+\\-!\\(\\){}\\[\\]^\"~*?:\\\\]|[&\\|]{2})";

String myStringToEscape = "ABC^ \" ~ * ? :DEF";
String myEscapedString = myStringToEscape.replaceAll(regex, "\\\\$1");

System.out.println(myEscapedString);
```

This will output:

```
ABC\^ \" \~ \* \? \:DEF
```