# What is the Java API to escape Elasticsearch special characters?

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch

I'm trying to perform the following query with the Java API:

```
"query": {
  "bool" : {
    "must" : [ {
      "field" : {
        "space-time-id.timestamp" : "2014-03-17T16:57:47.136-07:00"
      }
    } ]
  }
}
```

This fails presumably because the value has colons (which are special characters). Can someone point me to the Java API that escapes such characters?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to escape all Special Characters from whole string at one go in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22031329/how-to-escape-all-special-characters-from-whole-string-at-one-go-in-java)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParser.escape()`

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `org.apache.lucene.queryparser.flexible.standard.QueryParserUtil.escape()`

;)

Looks like the implementation is the same..